# WordPress membership and user area

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have an ecommerce wordpress site, I'm trying to know how to do the following:

Visitors can register and have their profiles, Then I be able to send them individually a PDF file so each user will get a different pdf file, This pdf will be shown in their profile and an email will be sent to the user when I post pdf for him.

I hope there is a plugin can do that or anything I can do to get it done.
Please help me out to achieve that.

Thank you very much

Comment: The PDF must be server-side generated and sent automatically or you must do everything by your hand?

Comment: @Optiroot , Manually, I write it myself